# Difference between IComparable and IComparable<T> in this search method

Tags: c#, icomparable, icomparablet

I know that there is a big difference between `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` in general, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301277/icomparable-and-icomparablet), but in this search method it will not make any difference, or will it?

```
public static int Search<T>(List<T> a, T target) where T : IComparable
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    {
        if (target.CompareTo(a[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

compared to:

```
public static int Search<T>(List<T> a, T target) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Both will work and give the same result, or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Both will work and give the same result, or not?

Let's look at what the compiler emits for both search methods:

```
Search:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0002:  br.s        IL_0025
IL_0004:  ldarga.s    01 
IL_0006:  ldarg.0     
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0008:  callvirt    06 00 00 0A 
IL_000D:  box         03 00 00 1B <---- Notice this!
IL_0012:  constrained. 03 00 00 1B 
IL_0018:  callvirt    System.IComparable.CompareTo
IL_001D:  brtrue.s    IL_0021
IL_001F:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0020:  ret         
IL_0021:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0022:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0023:  add         
IL_0024:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0025:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0026:  ldarg.0     
IL_0027:  callvirt    08 00 00 0A 
IL_002C:  blt.s       IL_0004
IL_002E:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_002F:  ret         

SearchGeneric:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0002:  br.s        IL_0020
IL_0004:  ldarga.s    01 
IL_0006:  ldarg.0     
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0008:  callvirt    06 00 00 0A 
IL_000D:  constrained. 03 00 00 1B 
IL_0013:  callvirt    09 00 00 0A 
IL_0018:  brtrue.s    IL_001C
IL_001A:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_001B:  ret         
IL_001C:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_001D:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_001E:  add         
IL_001F:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0020:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0021:  ldarg.0     
IL_0022:  callvirt    08 00 00 0A 
IL_0027:  blt.s       IL_0004
IL_0029:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_002A:  ret
```

If you look carefully, you'll see that the main difference is the fact that each call in `Search`, prior to invoking `CompareTo` has to **box the value** (this is notable with the `box` operation), as the non-generic version accepts a `object` type.

Let's try to analyze the performance differences between the two using a [*value type*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). I'm going to use [`BenchmarkDotNet`](https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet), which is a little (and truly awesome) benchmarking framework, which takes care of JITing, CPU warmup, etc.

Test:

```
[BenchmarkTask(platform: BenchmarkPlatform.X86)]
[BenchmarkTask(platform: BenchmarkPlatform.X64)]
public class Test
{
    private readonly List<int> list = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToList();

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestSearch()
    {
        Search(list, 999999);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestSearchGeneric()
    {
        SearchGeneric(list, 999999);
    }

    public static int Search<T>(List<T> a, T target) where T : IComparable
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            if (target.CompareTo(a[i]) == 0)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static int SearchGeneric<T>(List<T> a, T target) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            if (target.CompareTo(a[i]) == 0)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
***** Competition: Finish  *****

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.7.8.0
OS=Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
Processor=Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz, ProcessorCount=4
HostCLR=MS.NET 4.0.30319.42000, Arch=32-bit
Type=Test  Mode=Throughput  Jit=HostJit  .NET=HostFramework


            Method | Platform |    AvrTime |    StdDev |   op/s |
------------------ |--------- |----------- |---------- |------- |
        TestSearch |      X64 | 35.8065 ms | 3.3439 ms |  27.93 |
 TestSearchGeneric |      X64 |  4.6427 ms | 0.3075 ms | 215.40 |
        TestSearch |      X86 | 26.4876 ms | 1.4776 ms |  37.75 |
 TestSearchGeneric |      X86 |  6.6500 ms | 0.1664 ms | 150.38 |

***** Competition: End *****
```

See that the non-generic method incurring the boxing operation is **more than 4x slower** on x86 and **more than 8x slower** on x64. This can have a an impact on your applications performance.

I would generally not use the non-generic `IComparable`, which is mainly around for backwards compatibility to the days prior to generics. Note that another not-less important factor is the type safety which you gain with generics.

Answer (score 3):

It's a huge difference, the first method is boxing value types for no reason.

Comment: @DieterMeemken, only for value types

Comment: @DieterMeemken, not just for value types, using `IEnumerable` will also result in casts to get the right objects out. That's another performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

The first one `(i.e. IComparable)` implement not the generic type and is not related to the type used for parent class, but the second one (i.e. `IComparable<T>`) is Type safe where you can use only the type that you have specified for parent class.

Comment: But the comparing will work with both the same way, or not?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest difference should be obvious: the version `where T : IComparable` can be used with types that implement `IComparable`. The version `where T : IComparable<T>` can be used with types that implement `IComparable<T>`. Commonly used types that implement `IComparable` but not `IComparable<T>` are the various `System.Tuple<...>` generic types, as well as all enumeration types.

Comment: So there is only a difference in the possible types i can use for T?

Comment: Functionally, yes. There's no rule saying that a type that implements `IComparable` also has to implement `IComparable<T>`, or vice versa. Performance-wise, there can also be a difference, as pointed out by Blindy, but that should be a secondary concern: if the `IComparable<T>` version would be faster, except you can't call it, it's not of much use to you.