# Why doesn't IComparable<T> inherit from IComparable?

Tags: c#, interface, comparable, contravariance, icomparable

In most places I read that it is a good idea to inherit from both `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` in your classes to provide compatibility with non-generic collections. My question is why `IComparable<T>` doesn't inherit from `IComparable` by default then? The backward compatibility would be achieved this way.

For example, `IEnumerable<T>` does inherit from `IEnumerable`, so why don't do the same thing with `IComparable`? I read about variances, but I still don't really understand why it was designed that way. I tried to create a small example with interfaces with the same architecture, and it works as intended.

Edit:
Also, Microsoft documentation states the following:
Generic interfaces can inherit from non-generic interfaces if the generic interface is contravariant, which means it only uses its type parameter as a return value. In the .NET Framework class library, `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable` because `IEnumerable<T>` only uses T in the return value of `GetEnumerator` and in the `Current` property getter.

But despite that, one can inherit `IComparable` from `IComparable<T>` just fine (if you create interfaces with same architectures, that is).

Comment: Probably [gives an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16492085/11683). (And it would not be applicable to IEnumerable.)

Comment: I saw that question, when I tried to look up mine. Though it just describes the possible implementation of a class with both interfaces. My question is why `IComparable<T>` doesn't inherit from `IComparable` in the first place.

Comment: This question can only be answered by the designers of the language. Other answers will be guesses and supposition. See for example the Meta question [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/215552)

Answer (score 0):

Try it yourself if type is not specified then class which implement generic interface would also need to implement default type method

```
    public interface IFoo
    {
        void Foo(object o);
    }

    public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo
    {
        void Foo(T o);
    }
```

which turns into

```
public class Foo : IFoo<int>
    {
        void IFoo<int>.Foo(int o)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IFoo.Foo(object o)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

In this case you implement one interface with one method and it appear you must implement two methods wheres you inherit from typed interface

Comment: So, the main issue is that it's not obvious that you should implement two methods instead of just one with such inheritance?

Comment: How about class Foo : IFoo<object> ?

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to a Language Design decision, so short of a word of devs we can only guess.

One good reason is certainly that one is generic, the other not. Generics are inherently superior to the non-generic solution (wich means using object as a type) as they maintain type safety at compile time. So there was propably an intentional choice to break with the pre-generic version. To avoid downwards compatibiltiy. Notice how most classes that implement the Generic Version, do not implement it's non-generic counterpart. Really fundamental and old stuff like string are the exception - because they could not remove the old Interface, only add new ones.

With enumerators, the need seems less extreme. Enumerators are usually generated instead off or from a collection and fore purely reading processing. So you either have a fixed type to cast too or a fixed type to use in the Enumerator.

Another reason is propably that code that uses IComparable either explicitly demands it (type constraints) or consists of stuff made from it - and is itself generic by definition. Most often it is used for sort functions in **generic** collections. It is possible they did not want to use old collections anymore. And not supporting IComparable on Dictionary was certainly a good choice to get HashTable (it's pre-generic counterpart) out of circulation.